# What is native ad in admob?

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I am confused about native add in admob which is new ad format of google.
I have gone through [this link](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6066199), but could not understand much about this new ad format and also the benefit of this ad format.
Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply an ad that inserts itself between your other contents.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

AdMob uses the term "native" to describe ads for which publishers get to control the presentation. They can customize colors, fonts, positioning, and so on, in order to make the ads look and feel native to their app.

AdMob has two types of native ads: Native Ads Express and Native Ads Advanced. [This guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native) explains the differences between them.